# How to make your own Flutter widgets?

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation, flutter-design

So now I am an Intermediate flutter developer. I have used Material Design and Cupertino Design so far. I tried to use the new Fluent App design but it was a bad experience(this package has poor documentation). So what if, I need to design my own Style of Ui, how can I design my own designed widgets ??? I use illustrator/figma/xd to design. How to make the graphics work for flutter? How does this custom design thing work?

Comment: check this https://www.raywenderlich.com/10126984-creating-reusable-custom-widgets-in-flutter

Answer (score 0):

There is already an answer with this question on stackoverflow

Kindly [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59387313/11789675) to get that answer